# Simple Passive and Simple Active Gerunds

Tags: passive-voice, gerunds

Why is the first sentence wrong?

> Sarah's kitten loves holding.  She holds it every day.

It seems correct.  For example:

> I like dancing.
>
> He enjoys swimming.
>
> Alice likes running and jumping.

Comment: Could the person who voted to close please say why?

Comment: Crickets...  I would like to know why someone voted down my question, and I even asked the moderators on chat.  No response.

Answer (score 1):

We should use the simple passive gerund because the kitten is not the doer of the action.

> Her kitten loves **being held**.

Simple passive gerunds have this form:  being + past participle.

However, some verbs carry a passive sense, and the simple active gerund can be used.  For example:

> The roses require **watering**.
>
> Wordsworth's poetry is well worth **reading**.
>
> Your passport needs **signing**.